# How to draw 2 merging trees using an adjacency matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, tree

I have an adjacency matrix describing two trees that merges in the middle. An exemple for 10 nodes:
[image]

The corresponding adjacency matrix is a 10x10 matrix where the first row correspond to the first node (start of the first tree, node #1) and the last row to the root of the second tree (end of the second tree, node #10).

Here is the adjacency matrix corresponding to a larger example with 22 nodes:

```
0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0
```

I'm trying to plot this adjacency matrix as the picture showed above using Matlab. Matlab as some tools for plotting trees, for example the code given in:
https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2017/03/20/morse-code-binary-trees-and-graphs/

However, using the previous matrix (let's label it 'A') and the following code:

```
G = digraph(A);
Gp = plot(G);
```

does not produce a tree, but a graph (not ordered as a tree).

Thus, how to produce a picture of a tree (as showed above) using 'A' in Matlab?

Please note that I also have matrices describing trees where the degree between the children nodes are 3 (or more) rather than 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Zero-out half of your adjacency matrix to make the connection one-way.*

---

By default, MATLAB tries to decide the layout of graphs automatically, based on the structure of your graph. There are a few different [graph layouts](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.graphplot.layout.html#buxdj61-method) you can choose from.

The option you wanted is the `'Layered'` layout; but I tested it with your example, and [it definitely still doesn't look like a tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWNcW.png). **The reason being that your adjacency matrix is symmetrical, and the connection is two-way.** This confuses MATLAB when placing the nodes, and it doesn't think it's a tree.

The easy fix, is you can zero-out the lower triangular half of your adjacency matrix. I used the function [`tril`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tril.html) for this.

```
% Create a lower triangular matrix with the dimension of A,
idx = tril(ones(size(A)));

% Make it a logical array to select matrix elements with
idx = logical(idx);

% Select the defined lower triangular part, and set that to zero
A(idx) = 0;

% Generate-Plot graph as you did
G = digraph(A);
plot(G)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89nDx.png)